# Prove $\nabla(\frac{\vec{r}}{r}.\vec{r'})=-\frac{\vec{r}}{r}\times\left(\frac{\vec{r}}{r}\times\frac{\vec{r'}}{r}\right)$

Tags: vector-analysis, electromagnetism

How to prove the following,
$$\nabla\left(\frac{\vec{r}}{r}.\vec{r'}\right)=-\frac{\vec{r}}{r}\times\left(\frac{\vec{r}}{r}\times\frac{\vec{r'}}{r}\right)$$
where $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{r'}$ are two different position vectors.

I started the calculation in the following way,
$$\nabla(\vec{a}.\vec{b})=(\vec{a}.\nabla)\vec{b}+(\vec{b}.\nabla)\vec{a}+\vec{a}\times(\nabla\times \vec{b})+\vec{b}\times(\nabla\times \vec{a})$$

so,
$$\nabla\left(\frac{\vec{r}}{r}.\vec{r'}\right)=\left(\frac{\vec{r}}{r}.\nabla\right)\vec{r'}+(\vec{r'}.\nabla)\frac{\vec{r}}{r}+\frac{\vec{r}}{r}\times(\nabla\times \vec{r'})+\vec{r'}\times\left(\nabla\times \frac{\vec{r}}{r}\right)$$

Now,
$$\vec{r'}\times\left(\nabla\times \frac{\vec{r}}{r}\right)=\vec{r'}\times\left(\nabla\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)\times\vec{r}+\frac{1}{r}(\nabla\times\vec{r})\right)=0$$

Also,
$$\left(\frac{\vec{r}}{r}.\nabla\right)\vec{r'},\frac{\vec{r}}{r}\times(\nabla\times \vec{r'})=0$$
as $\vec{r'}$ is independent of $\vec{r}$,

I am stuck here, I don't know how to calculate $(\vec{r'}.\nabla)\frac{\vec{r}}{r}$.

Comment: On the left-hand side you have a derivative (a nabla). On the right-hand side you have none, so must get rid of it somehow. Is there any rule you could use to expand the nabla or "take" it?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to derive the identity. The derivation proceeds as follows,

For a radius vector $\vec{R}=\vec{r}-\vec{r'}$, the magnitude becomces,
$$R^2=r^2-2\vec{r}.\vec{r'}+r'^2$$
$$\implies \nabla\left(\frac{R^2}{r}\right)=\nabla(r)-2\nabla(\vec{r}.\vec{r'})+\nabla\left(\frac{r'^2}{r}\right)\\
\implies \frac{2rR\nabla(R)-R^2\nabla(r)}{r^2}=\hat{r}-2\nabla(\vec{r}.\vec{r'})+r'^2\nabla\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)\\
\implies 2\frac{\vec{R}}{r}-R^2\frac{\hat{r}}{r^2}=\frac{\vec{r}}{r}-2\nabla(\vec{r}.\vec{r'})-r'^2\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}\\
\implies \left(\frac{\vec{R}-\vec{r}}{r}\right)+\frac{\vec{R}}{r}-\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}(R^2-r'^2)=-2\nabla(\vec{r}.\vec{r'})\\
\implies -\left(\frac{\vec{r'}}{r}\right)+\frac{\vec{R}}{r}-\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}(r^2-2(\vec{r}.\vec{r'}))=-2\nabla(\vec{r}.\vec{r'})\\
\implies -\left(\frac{\vec{r'}}{r}\right)+\left(\frac{\vec{R}-\vec{r}}{r}\right)+2(\vec{r}.\vec{r'})\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}=-2\nabla(\vec{r}.\vec{r'})\\
\implies 2\left(\frac{\vec{r'}}{r}\right)-2(\vec{r}.\vec{r'})\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}=2\nabla(\vec{r}.\vec{r'})$$
Now from the triple product identity of the vector one could write,
$$\vec{a}\times(\vec{b}\times\vec{c})=\vec{b}(\vec{a}.\vec{c})-\vec{c}(\vec{a}.\vec{b})$$
So,
$$\vec{r}\times(\vec{r}\times\vec{r'})=\vec{r}(\vec{r}.\vec{r'})-\vec{r'}(\vec{r}.\vec{r})\\
\implies \frac{\vec{r}\times(\vec{r}\times\vec{r'})}{r^3}=\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}(\vec{r}.\vec{r'})-\frac{\vec{r'}}{r}\\
\implies \frac{\vec{r}\times(\vec{r}\times\vec{r'})}{r^3}+\frac{\vec{r'}}{r}=\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}(\vec{r}.\vec{r'})$$
Putting this back into the above equation gives the proves the identity in the question.